# GMT .setHours don't working properly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm trying to set the end of the start day, for do this I'll set `23` hours from the start date but the end result display me a wrong date with `22` hours. I can explain better with my code:

```
var currDateEndTemp = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.toDate();
console.log("End =>" , currDateEndTemp);
var currDateEnd = new Date(currDateEndTemp).toUTCString();
console.log("CurrDateEnd => " , currDateEnd);
currDateEnd = new Date(currDateEnd).setHours(23);
console.log("Set hours =>" , currDateEnd);
currDateEnd = new Date(currDateEnd).toUTCString();
console.log("UTC => " , currDateEnd);
```

**OUTPUT**

> End => Mon Oct 26 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
>   CurrDateEnd =>  Mon, 26 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT
>   Set hours => 1445896800000
>   UTC =>  Mon, 26 Oct 2015 22:00:00 GMT

But the end result should be:

```
Mon, 26 Oct 2015 23:59:59 GMT
```

or something like. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not considering daylight saving time, nor are you setting minutes.

Since the `View` object's `start` property is a moment, if you want the end-of-day of the start of the view, then just get it like this:

```
var m = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start;
var end = m.clone().endOf('day');
```

You can then call `toDate`, or `format`, or whatever you want from there.